# Two threads try to read/write some data into the same row of the table in database

Tags: c++, database, multithreading, postgresql

If two threads are trying to update the same table's row then how do we queue the process. The two threads are updating  the row in a given table, and i require the code to queue the process that it is receiving after the first thread untill the thread is finished executing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

using namespace std;
using namespace pqxx;

static int lock = 1;

void threadFn1()
{

    char *sql;
    cout << "I sm inside a thread1\n";

    if (lock == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            connection C("dbname=test user=postgres password=Shivy8896$ hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
            if (C.is_open())
            {
                cout << "Opened database from thread1";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "CAn't open database";
            }

            work W(C);
            sql = "UPDATE person SET last_name='kumar' where id=2";
            W.exec(sql);
            W.commit();
        }
    }
}
void threadFn2()
{
    cout << "I am inside thread2\n";

    char *sql;

    if (lock == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            connection C("dbname=test user=postgres password=Shivy8896$ hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
            if (C.is_open())
            {
                cout << "Opened database from thread1";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "CAn't open database";
            }

            work W(C);
            sql = "UPDATE person SET last_name='kumar2' where id=2";
            W.exec(sql);
            W.commit();

        }
    }
}

int main()

{

    thread t1(threadFn1);
    thread t2(threadFn2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Untrelated: missing a `catch` block in `threadFn1` and `threadFn2`.

Comment: Unrelated: `sql = "UPDATE person SET last_name='kumar' where id=2";` uses a non `const` pointer to point at a `const` value. This is illegal in modern C++ because it prevents accidental writes into non-writable space .

Comment: std::mutex. search for that

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to handle this kind of concurrency yourself, the database does it automatically for you.

Each update will put a lock on the row for the duration of the transaction, so the updates are automatically serialized.